# Combine Multiple Separate Column into 1 in excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have a file with the following columns: Factory, PO, Item, Date, ETA
These columns repeat themselves horizontally 30 times. I would like to be able to combine each respective column in to 1. In essence all Factory columns into 1, PO into a separate and so on. I started with the following code below but realized it doesn't account for blank space as well as it just copies one column right after another. It doesn't copy the respective columns that I need.

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long

    For i = 2 To 4
        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LR, i)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet4").Select
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Next i

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("A1:A" & LR)
       .Value = .Value
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
         Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    On Error GoTo 0

    End Sub
```

![Example][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk9FL.jpg

To clarify a bit more, I do not want to concatenate. I am including a picture of sample data. Using the sample data as a reference point, I would essentially like to take all this data and combine into a separate workbook as follows:

- Combine column A with BU, B with BV and so forth.
- Pull all the data from Column A and put into new workbook Column A
- Pull column BU data and place underneath column A data in new workbook column A
- Do the same with B and BV and so forth

Hope that clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Could you show some before / after pictures so we have a little bit more to work on?

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the contents of the columns? And when you say it "doesn't account for blank space", what would you like it to do for blank columns: skip the column, insert a hard-coded number of spaces, or what?

Comment: Sorry couldn't add pic so included link above